# Failed to install Vue.js Cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-cli

```
node -v: v8.10.0

npm -v: 3.5.2
```

While running `npm install -g @vue/cli` or `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` I get the error below and failed to download Vue CLI

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a rather old version of npm. The current version is 6.9.0, and the packages you are working with are asking for npm >= 5.5.1.

You need to update your node version, if possible always use latest node version

```
Nodejs version 14.4.
```

And if you have project that required different node version then use

```
NVM - node version manager
```

Just use sudo for global install

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Comment: i already used sudo npm install -g @vue/cli but it didn't work and got the same error

Comment: Hi @TarunJain updated my answer.

Comment: This worked for me Thank you so much

Comment: for updating this can be used
" sudo npm cache clean -f " and 

" sudo npm install -g n " then
" sudo n stable "

Thank you